# Trouble redirecting after submiting files with Axios using React form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm kinda new with React and JS in general so I'm not quite familiar with these kinds of applications. Anyway, I'm trying to redirect to another page after I submit a form that requires some files. I'm using Mullter and Axios to upload the files to the backend, where I am going to process the files and return the redirection if the process was succesful.

**React.js code**

```
import React, { setFile,useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, useLocation } from 'react-router'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import './SomeCss.css';
import axios from "axios";

function FileUpload() {
  const [hoteles, setHoteles] = useState("");
  const [aplicapromo, setAplicaPromo] = useState(false)
  const [uploadFile, setUploadFile] = React.useState();
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const onChangeFile = e => {
    setUploadFile(e.target.files);
  };

  const handleChangeCheckbox = () => {
    setAplicaPromo(!aplicapromo);
  };
  
  const submitForm = (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    const dataArray = new FormData();
    dataArray.append('hoteles', hoteles);
    dataArray.append('aplicapromo', aplicapromo);
    for (let i = 0 ; i < uploadFile.length ; i++) {
      dataArray.append('archivos', uploadFile[i]);
  }
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/upload", dataArray, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setSubmitted(true)
        alert(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       alert(error)
      });
  };
  if (submitted) {
    return <Redirect push to={{
      pathname: '/DisplayResults',
    }}
    />
  }
  return (
    <div className="SubirFiles-MainContainer ">

      <Form onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>
          Please select the necesary files and fill the form.
        </p>
        <hr />
        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            Files
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control onChange={onChangeFile} variant="dark" name="archivos" accept=".xls, .xlsx" type="file" multiple  />
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            Hotel List
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control type="text" value={hoteles} onChange={(e) => setHoteles(e.target.value)}  
            name="hoteles" required className="mb-3" 
            placeholder="placeholder" />
          </Col>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
           Pleause use the correct format
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Row}>
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            Apply Discount
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Check type="checkbox" defaultChecked={aplicapromo} 
              onChange={handleChangeCheckbox}
              name="aplicapromo" className="mb-3" id="cboxpromos" />
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button as="input" type="submit" variant="dark" value="Continuar" />{' '}
      </Form>
    </div>

  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <FileUpload />;
}
```

This is the backend code, which recieves a Post petition with the files and the information from the FORM

**Backend Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const fs = require('fs')
const multer = require('multer');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require('path')
const functions = require("./functions");
dotenv.config();
app.use(cors('*'));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, process.env.CARPETA)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    fs.access(path.join(process.env.CARPETA, file.originalname), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
      } else {
        fs.rename(path.join(process.env.CARPETA, file.originalname), path.join(process.env.CARPETA, +Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname), function (err) {
          if (err) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
          cb(null, file.originalname)
        });
      }
    });
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('GET OK');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/upload', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('GET upload');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

// Upload Endpoint
app.post("/upload", upload.array("archivos"), uploadFiles);

async function uploadFiles(req, res) {
  //console.dir(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log(req.body.hoteles);
  console.log(req.body.aplicapromo);
  let aplicapromo = (req.body.aplicapromo === 'true')
  let hotelstring = req.body.hoteles
  let objeto = await functions.SomeProcess(aplicapromo, hotelstring)
  console.log(objeto)
  if (objeto.error) {

    console.log("error")
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: objeto.descerror,
      errors: objeto.error
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log("Process succesful")
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Process complete, redirecting to next page..."
    })
  }
}



app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server Started...'));
```

After I submit the files the process seems to be working, however , once that the process is finished, I don't receive anything on the client-side. Also, since the function that processes the files is quite long, I'm using async syntax, I don't know if I'm doing anything badly or if missing something, so any kind of help would be great! :)

Comment: Firstly I wrap up the files and the information from the Form into a FormData, which I send to the back-end with Axios, There, i receive the Post petition and I use Multer to upload the files into a folder, later on, I read the body request which contains the path of the files and the information from the form. functions.SomeProcess receives the paths and the form information, which returns either a true or false

Comment: I see that you're using the multer service to handle the upload. Without a try/catch block, your async function might fail silently. Are you getting your "Process successful" log message?

Comment: Nope, I'm not getting anything, only the status from the process (if failed or not).